# Sending discount amount using paypal PHP REST API

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal PHP REST API for creating payment.

Everything is working fine(applying tax and shipping ) but I am not able to sending discount amount using PHP API.

We are implementing Magento custom connectors for shopping cart. In this we are configured the ‘shopping cart pricing rules’($10.00 discount) for each category.

Is there any way to send discount amount using PHP REST API ?

Comment: Hey have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951530/discounts-via-paypal-rest-api-sample/24000405#24000405

Answer (score 0):

You can send an item with a negative amount as a workaround.  Not ideal, but better than nothing.  See [this thread](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/55).